# Compute new variable based on multiple arguments in subsets of dataframe

Tags: r, database

I'm working with a large database consisting of multiple studies with over 100.000 rows. The study sizes vary from 300 to over 10.000, and more studies are added regularly.

I want to calculate a reference interval for h1 and h2 per study, excluding cases which don't fulfill the criteria. After that I want to count the cases which are outside these reference ranges, but using all of the cases this time. I want to do this per study and preferably with a loop or a split by study, since new studies are added regularly. In this way I don't have to alter the code every time a new study is added.

I've tried a for loop and group_by(), but both don't work unfortunately.

Consider this data.frame:

```
df <- data.frame(study = rep(LETTERS[1:3], each = 4), 
                 h1 = c(2, 3, 8, 4, 5, 8, 1, 6, 7, 8, NA, 11), 
                 h2 = c(10, 12, 9, 14, 15, 16, 20, 19, 11, 12, 14, 18),
                 v1 = c(0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1), 
                 v2 = c(0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0))
df

# Groups:   study [3]
   study    h1    h2    v1    v2
   <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
 1 A         2    10     0     0
 2 A         3    12     0     1
 3 A         8     9     1     0
 4 A         4    14     0     0
 5 B         5    15     0     0
 6 B         8    16     0     0
 7 B         1    20     1     1
 8 B         6    19     0     0
 9 C         7    11     0     0
10 C         8    12     0     0
11 C        NA    14     0     0
12 C        11    18     1     0
```

I want to calculate a reference interval per study, excluding cases which have a "1" for v1 or v2. So for example the first study:

```
   > quantile(df$h1[df$study == "A" & df$v1 == 0 & df$v2 == 0], prob = c(0.05, 0.95), na.rm = TRUE)
     5% 95% 
    2.1 3.9 
   > quantile(df$h2[df$study == "A" & df$v1 == 0 & df$v2 == 0], prob = c(0.05, 0.95), na.rm = TRUE)
      5%  95% 
    10.2 13.8
```

Now I want to compute a new variable which is "1" if h1 >= upper limit of ref interval q1 and h2 < lower limit of q2. Otherwise it would become a "0", or "NA" if any NA's are present in the used variables h1 and h2.

I've tried this for-loop:

```
library(dplyr)    
for (i in levels(df$study)){
      
      q1 <- quantile(df$h1[df$study == i & df$v1 == 0 & df$v2 == 0], prob = c(0.05, 0.95), na.rm = TRUE)
      q2 <- quantile(df$h2[df$study == i & df$v1 == 0 & df$v2 == 0], prob = c(0.05, 0.95), na.rm = TRUE)
      
      df <- df %>% 
        mutate(x1 = if_else(study == i & h1 >= q1[2] & h2 < q2[1], 1, 0))  
    }
```

Which doesnt work unfortunately. Also, if it would work I think it would have resulted in a loop which would overwrite its own results. I've also tried using dplyr and group_by;

```
df <- df %>% group_by(study)
  mutate(x1 = ifelse((df$h1 >= quantile(df$h1[df$v1 == 0 & df$v2 == 0], prob = c(0.95), na.rm = TRUE) &
                      df$h2 <  quantile(df$h2[df$v1 == 0 & df$v2 == 0], prob = c(0.05), na.rm = TRUE)), 1, 0))
```

But this gives me an error: no applicable method for 'mutate' applied to an object of class "c('double', 'numeric')".

It should result in a new variable x1, and the first study should be 0, 0, 1, 0. Does anyone have a tip have to tackle this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you want only upper quantile of `h1` and lower one of `h2` calculate only those and add them as new columns to compare.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(study) %>%
  mutate(val1 = quantile(h1[v1 == 0 & v2 == 0], prob = 0.95, na.rm = TRUE), 
         val2 = quantile(h2[v1 == 0 & v2 == 0], prob = 0.05, na.rm = TRUE),
         x1 = as.integer(h1 >= val1 & h2 <= val2), 
         x1 = replace(x1, is.na(h1) | is.na(h2), NA)) %>%
  ungroup -> df
df

#   study    h1    h2    v1    v2  val1  val2    x1
#   <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <int>
# 1 A         2    10     0     0  3.9   10.2     0
# 2 A         3    12     0     1  3.9   10.2     0
# 3 A         8     9     1     0  3.9   10.2     1
# 4 A         4    14     0     0  3.9   10.2     0
# 5 B         5    15     0     0  7.8   15.1     0
# 6 B         8    16     0     0  7.8   15.1     0
# 7 B         1    20     1     1  7.8   15.1     0
# 8 B         6    19     0     0  7.8   15.1     0
# 9 C         7    11     0     0  7.95  11.1     0
#10 C         8    12     0     0  7.95  11.1     0
#11 C        NA    14     0     0  7.95  11.1    NA
#12 C        11    18     1     0  7.95  11.1     0
```

Comment: Thank you Ronak Shah, this solution indeed solves some of my problems, only the computation of x1 does not account for the NA's in the dataset and leads to a 0 in row 11. I cant seem to find an easy way to fix this.